# dropdownlist...Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "a"

Tags: java, selenium

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");
Select selectname = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/a"))));
    selectname.selectByIndex(2);
```

Here i am finding out the xpath by using firebug and firepath
which shows the firepath of dropdownlist of leads as

**also i tried to take partial xpath but easch and every time its showing different xpath,so i proceed with the absoulte xpath

[lead dropdownlist xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUVmp.png)

Comment: share the relevant HTML for drop down with select and option tags

Comment: <a aria-required="true" class="select" aria-disabled="false" aria-describedby="40:2153;a-label" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" role="button" title="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="50:2153;a" data-interactive-lib-uid="5">--None--</a>

Comment: While taking Xpath the last tag is 'a'..where as per the exception its showing it must be 'select' tag which i am not getting from the xpath by firepath

Comment: Please paste the complete HTML from select

Comment: check in firbug/firepath for select tag , mostly drop downs are construct in that way , but you never know it could be divs and spans too.

Comment: checked but showing the same..image is pasted in the question..please check

Comment: Yes i got it its a div and under div tag there is a <a> tag..So i tired to take xpath of that div and the popup is shown also..but not able to select the required <li>value

Answer (score 0):

`Select` can be only used on `<select>` tag.

If you want to perform select on `<a>` element, you have to create a workaround.
The workaround would look like this:

1. Click on dropdown
2. Click on a displayed value

Example:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), ''--None--')]"));
dropdown.click();
WebElement value = driver.findElement(here insert locator for displayed value in dropdown list);
value.click();
```

**The answer to the comment:**

First, you need to know what tag your values have. Is it `<div>`? Is it `<li>`? 
Then, you can search the values by visible text via `XPath`. Let's assume, it's `<div>`

```
WebElement myDesiredValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'value text')]"));
myDesiredValue.click();
```

If you want to click the desired index, without looking for specific value, you have to use `findElements()` method. Depends on the HTML, you would have to provide a selector which selects ALL values like this:

```
List<WebElement> allValues = driver.findElements(my locator);
allValues.get(0).click() //0 is first value OR current selected value in dropdown. So, selecting the 2nd index would be more like allValues.get(1).click();
```

Comment: what if i want to automate the click event also, like i want to click for the 2nd index from the displayed value ..then what to write,could you please help me with this?

Comment: @JollyPriya I edited my answer to answer your comment

Comment: allValues.get(0).click()..in this get(int index) is present..means i have to provide the index number which is integer,which is going correctly ...how to provide the String value to get()..

Comment: Also i m using one excel file in which the data to be clicked value is written..so i am fetching data from excel file and then writing that data to be populated in the dropdownlist

Comment: @JollyPriya To provide String value to get use `Integer.parseInt("my string");`

Comment: @JollyPriya But it has to be numeric. In other case use searching with `value text` just like I wrote in my answer :)

Comment: WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/a ")));
  dropdown.click();

Comment: How to use 'value text' while using By.xpath();i dont know how to use.Also there is no <div> or <li>

Comment: @JollyPriya Value text is a value you want to select from dropdown. If Dropdown contains list of Countries and you want to select "India" you use `By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'India')]`

Comment: its a div and under that<ul><li><a></li></ul> and the xpath is "html/body/div[10]/div/ul/li[3]/a" by this div is poped up..byut not able to select the li[3] which i required....also i checked with your answer By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Ms')"].which is not working

Comment: @JollyPriya Start a new question. This topic starts getting too broad. Add relevant HTML code as `code` not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the dropdown using xpath and then Locate the value

```
WebElement dropdown_arrow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[(text()='--None--')]"));
dropdown_arrow.click();
WebElement dropdown_value = driver.findElement("Locator value");
dropdown_value.click();
```

you can also use this xpath for drop down

```
WebElement dropdown_arrow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='select'][(text()='--None--')]"));
dropdown_arrow.click();
WebElement dropdown_value = driver.findElement("Locator value");
dropdown_value.click();
```

Comment: what if i want to automate the click event also, like i want to automate the click for the 2nd index from the displayed value

Comment: then u have two pass locator value of 2nd value or u have to use if else

Comment: how to do?dropdown_value.click();

Comment: Where is locatyor\

Comment: By.xpath("html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/fieldset/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/a")...or a div is poped up whose xpath is  "html/body/div[10]/div/ul/li[4]/a"...i am able to get the div under which <li> is present but not able to select the li[3] item